# XCTest inconsistency when making Objective-C comparisons in Swift unit test

Tags: objective-c, swift, xctest

I've just written a unit test in Swift 2.2 (Xcode v7.3.1) that asserts for a property being nil on an Objective-C object. When using `XCTAssert` with Swift's reference comparison operator, `===`, the result is correct.
But when using `XCTAssertNil`, the test incorrectly indicates the property under test is not nil:

```
XCTAssert(delegateWrapper.delegateObject === nil) // Correctly passes
XCTAssertNil(delegateWrapper.delegateObject)      // Incorrectly fails
```

The property in question, `delegateObject`, is unambiguously `nil`, as the debugger shows:

[image]

...can anyone please explain the inconsistency here?

**EDIT:**

Being a very simple wrapper to allow weak references in a collection of multiple delegates, the Objective-C declaration of the delegateWrapper's class is extremely basic and the implementation is literally empty, so I don't believe that's complicating the issue, unless the new Objective-C `nullable` property modifier has a bug / side effect:

```
@interface SLCommonAlertCenterDelegateWrapper : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, nullable, weak) id<SLCommonAlertCenterDelegate>delegateObject;

@end

@implementation SLCommonAlertCenterDelegateWrapper
@end
```

Comment: Is it possible you are either writing in Swift 2.2, using Xcode 7.3.1; or writing in Swift 2.3, using Xcode 8? I'm not aware that Swift 2.3 is released for Xcode 7.3.1, while Xcode 8 will ship will support for both Swift 2.3 and Swift 3

Comment: FWIW, I'm not able to replicate this with a brief test snippet in Xcode 7.3.1/Swift 2.2; nor Xcode 8/Swift 2.3. However, since my object setup is different from yours, it's possible I'm missing something crucial. Do you have a minimal object graph that demonstrates this?

Comment: @Palpatim My mistake: I meant Swift 2.2. Question corrected, along with declaration and implementation of the class in question. I'd be interested to know if this is a bug or something completely obvious that I've missed.

Comment: Not sure what to say. Even copying your `@interface` & `@implementation` (and creating an empty `@protocol`), the test passes for me in XCode 7.3.1, Swift 2.2. I'm wondering if there's something specific to your setup--perhaps you're using a singleton object, or somehow multi-threading your test code?

Comment: Huh, well thanks for checking it out. Might have to chalk this one up to the random test gods. Thanks again. D.